# Store Information Past Program Run Time Java

Tags: java, persistence

I have a terminal/console java program that runs and collects data. I would like that data to be saved even after the program quits. The data is in the format of two ArrayLists.

What is the best way to save them for use later?

My ideas:

- convert to GSON or JSON string --> write text file
- create database (unsure of type) save there
  open to other ideas...

One ArrayList has 4500 items the other 150 items. Both arrays hold Objects

I would prefer something that has a low learning curve over speed as data will only be read once at beginning of execution.

Comment: Depends on what you actually want to achieve. If you want the data to be stored on the local machine only why should you set up a database?

Comment: @TheLaw this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data, but I'd suggest CSV as an easy alternative. Treat each row as an object in the ArrayList and each column as attribute. Separate columns using `,`
Advantage is, it is easier to implement and read using excel or similar tool.

And, use the [Java File APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to save CSV to disk.

Comment: Short notice: There is no standardized column-delimiter in CSV-Files which could cause trouble when you are using some third party tools/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would largely depend on what is stored in the ArrayList.

If you are storing a primitive - String, Int, what have you - there is nothing wrong with CSV  or a simple file with each array entry on its own line.

If the ArrayList contains objects, then a formatted string like J(G)SON is a good way to go since the fields/values are stored in a meaningful way.

Or XML if you like that sort of thing (I don't like that sort of thing).

Answer (score 0):

1 Main task is not encoding, but serialize (and solve deep problems, if there are links between objects).

I suppose data collected are unrelated (no links between them).

to be serializable, your class must be like that

```
public class myclass implements Serializable
```

and you should (not mandatory) declare inside

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6569838532917408380L;
```

If anything inside in serializable too, it's OK (standard types are, collections, ...)

2 size : 4500 is little nowadays. A file is sufficient, if it is to write and reload after (I suppose objects are not too big).

3 why not binary => base 64 ?  it's little more natural than JSON ...

serial

```
     String serial= DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byteData);
```

deserial

```
     byte[] byteData_reverse=DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(serial);
```